# How to Open Fragement-2 which is in Activity-2 From Fragment Button in Activity-1

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have been trying a lot Unable to do it pls help out. I have two **Fragments**: fragment1 and fragment2 Activity1 as Fragement1 - in this fragment one there is a Button on it. Onclick of that Button the Fragment in Activity2 Should open.

```
      @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        View rootView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_tools, container, false);
        Button cntr = (Button) rootView.findViewById(R.id.counterid);
        cntr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                Fragment fragment = new ToolsFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
                fragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.fragmenttools,fragment).addToBackStack(null).commit();
            }
        });
        return rootView;
    }
```

Comment: If you are trying to open Fragment two in Activity two you have to use Intent of Activity 2

Comment: I will recommend to place both fragments in same activity

Comment: zaid see listen .. i have tablayout in that there is a fragemnet and button on it

Comment: i want open fragemnet which is on another activity on button click

Answer (score 0):

Each fragment belongs to its own activity, to open specific fragment of another activity, you should start second activity firstly, and open that fragment in `onCreate()` method as usual.